# Jest testing mock functions return undefined (create react app project)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, create-react-app

I'm working on a test case for a small react app with jest.
I have declared a mock function in the scope of the describe test block.

when I'm running the test in debug mode, I have stopped on a breakpoint inside the react component that receive the mocked function the mock was declared and the implementation was undefined.

does anyone know what the reason for this behaviour?

Thanks a lot!!!

```
 describe("Test App component", () => {
      describe("Test Component rendering", () => {
        const mockUtils = {
            debounceFunc: jest.fn((func) => {
              return func;
            }),
            isSomeStringEmpty: jest.fn(),
            confirmAction: jest.fn(),
          };
        test(`when render App component, then wrapper element should be rendered`, () => {
       
          render(<App utils={mockUtils} apiService={mockApiService} />);
    
          let appDiv = screen.getByTestId("app-test");
    
          expect(appDiv).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for that behaviour.
the reason was that I use creat-react-app for this project, and by default in react-scripts `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js` .
the jest configuration is set with `"resetMocks": true`

this mean that before every test jest reset all mocks.

by default JEST without creat-react-app configured with `"resetMocks": false`.

to change this configuration all you need to do is to add this entry `"jest": { "resetMocks": false }` at the root level of the package.json .[package.json example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQkau.png)